# Including local source code directories and files in aws-sam?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I work in a mono repo where I have a [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/index.html) (lambda) application. The structure is more or less like so:

```
.
├── my_folder1
    ├── file1.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── file2.py
    ├── my_folder2
    │   └── my_folder3
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── file3.py
    ├── sam-app
    │   ├── events
    │   │   └── event.json
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── samconfig.toml
    │   ├── template.yaml
    │   ├── tests
    │   └── hello_world
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── requirements.txt
                :preview:
                numpy
                pandas
                ...
    │       └── app.py
                :preview:
                import pandas
                from my_folder1.my_folder2.my_folder3.file3 import MyClass
                ...

    .
    .
    .
    more_folders...
    .
    .
    .
```

You can separate my application into three portions:

1. External pip packages like `pandas`, `numpy`, etc. These packages change rarely. Occassionally I add a new one. They take a long time to install. They need to be built in a docker container which corresponds to the lambda runtime (as anyone who has used numpy/pandas has learned the hard way).
2. Source code within the mono repo, implicitly called from my lambda. So if you are following along with the preview above.
   `my_folder1.my_folder2.my_folder3.file3` might look like:

   ```py
   from my_folder1.my_folder837278 import my_utility_function

   class MyClass:
       my_utility_function()

   ...
   ```

   This code changes often. Doesn't need to build in docker image.
3. My actual lambda code explicitly called by a handler within: `./my_folder1/sam-app/hello_world/app.py`

Let's say I run the `sam build --use-container` command. This is great! It creates `.aws-sam/build/MyFunction/pandas`, `.aws-sam/build/MyFunction/numpy`, etc. And these pip packages are built against amazon-linux and can be used by the lambda. The problem is that my local imports (e.g. `from my_folder1.my_folder2.my_folder3.file3 import MyClass`) will clearly fail.

**My question is: Is it possible to sync the local imports of my code to my sam application using the existing template specification?** [Best docs regarding template spec](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md)

Additional information:

- How I get around this currently?
  I write bash scripts that look like this and run them after `sam build --use-container`:

  ```
  .
  .
  .
  rsync "${EXCLUSIONS[@]}" -r $LOCAL_MODULES0 $LOCAL_MODULES1 ./.aws-sam/build/${FUNCTION}/my_folder2
  rsync "${EXCLUSIONS[@]}" -r $LOCAL_MODULES2 $LOCAL_MODULES3 ./.aws-sam/build/${FUNCTION}/
  .
  .
  .
  ```

  which copy/sync the relevant local directories into the build directory to seem as if they were pip installed. Because lambda must already have that folder in the python path.

  I also have one just for `./my_folder1/sam-app/hello_world/`.
- Things that suck:

  - Because the pip packages are so large you cannot view the lambda functional code in the UI. If they were layers and were put in /opt/python instead of /var/task, this would actually be possible.
- Things I want:

  - `sam build --use-container --dependencies` - Builds external packages (things installed with pip) on docker image. Takes a long time, but only need be done once (unless removed/added dependencies).
  - `sam build` - Since `--dependencies` isn't specified just mounts code within `./my_folder1/sam-app/hello_world/` along with any local directories specified in template.yaml
  - Pre build commands in template.yaml. Improves customizability.
  - `sam local invoke` - Should be `sam build && sam local invoke`
  - External dependencies (e.g. pip packages) should be made into layers by default. Uploaded to s3.

Comment: sam init --runtime python3.7?

Comment: Changing the runtime is unrelated :(

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html